# ios - Photo duplicated when adding to an album using PHAssetChangeRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, photos

When adding a photo to an album using the PHAssetChangeRequest the photo gets duplicated in the camera roll instead of just adding the existing photo to the album. Has anyone come across this issue before? All we are looking to do is add an existing photo to an album.

Thanks

Rich

> > Updated to remove different versions to show a version working with the duplication that's easier to read<<

```
// Save to the album
                       [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            NSLog(@"Here 1");
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imTransfer, 0);
            NSLog(@"Here 2");
            PHAssetChangeRequest *assetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
            placeholder = [assetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
            NSLog(@"Here 3");

            photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection
                                                                                                                          assets:photosAsset];
             NSLog(@"Here 4");
            [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];
        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (success)
            {
                NSLog(@"SUCCESS!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Maybe bug not here. Take attention, that it is SharedPhotoLibrary (singletone) and it async (block).

Comment: I've been looking in other parts of the code to see if the problem is elsewhere after reading your comment, and I haven't been able to spot the issue. I did discover that the photo does get added to the camera roll if I remove '[albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];' but it does not get added to the album

Comment: Sorry, hard to debug without debugger =)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new asset. If you want to use existing photo from the camera roll, you should not do that.

I assume you are using UIImagePickerController to select a photo.
Below is the code to get the asset details of the image from camera roll and add the same to custom collection:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //Custom function to get custom album
    PHAssetCollection *collection = [self getMyAlbum];

    NSError *error;
    __block NSString *localID;

    PHAsset *asset;
    if (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]) {

        NSURL *imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        PHFetchResult *imageFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[imageUrl] options:nil];
        asset = [imageFetchResult firstObject];
        localID = [asset localIdentifier];
    }

    if(localID) {

        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChangesAndWait:^{

            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection];
            [changeRequest addAssets:@[asset]];

        } error:&error];

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.